# Kameleo and "PageLoadStrategy"

Tags: kameleo

I am trying to change "PageLoadStrategy" for Selenium when launched via Kameleo but its not working.

This is the current JavaScript code that I'm using:

```
const { Builder, Capabilities } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const { PageLoadStrategy } = require("selenium-webdriver/lib/capabilities");

const KAMELEO_CLI_URL = process.env.KAMELEO_CLI_URL;

const capabilities = new Capabilities(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
capabilities.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);

const startSelenium = async (profileId) => {
    try {
        const builder = new Builder()
            .usingServer(`${KAMELEO_CLI_URL}/webdriver`)
            .withCapabilities({
                "kameleo:profileId": profileId,
                "browserName": "Kameleo",
                "setPageLoadStrategy": PageLoadStrategy.NONE,
                'pageLoadStrategy': PageLoadStrategy.NONE
            }, capabilities);

        const driver = await builder.build();

        return driver;
    } catch (error) {
        return { status: false, error };
    }
};

module.exports = { startSelenium };
```